# Increment the cell in Vlookup when dragging horizontally in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have a Vlookup formula in excel

```
=VLOOKUP($A2, Kenya!$A$2:$L$34,2,FALSE)
```

I'm trying to drag this formula in columns (to right side of the sheet) and I want the the row of the lookup value to increase instead of the column.

I have tried to use `OFFSET`, in someways it worked however it doesn't work when I drag it to right.

Comment: Try to use HLOOKUP function: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hlookup-function-a3034eec-b719-4ba3-bb65-e1ad662ed95f

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX($A:$A,COLUMN(),1), Kenya!$A$2:$L$34,2,FALSE)
```

Note that it would be better to change `$A:$A` to only include the rows where you expect to find data for the lookup value. For example, if you are dragging the formula to the right only 10 columns, just use `$A$1:$A$10` instead of `$A:$A`

As you drag this formula to the right, the `COLUMN()` will increment, which will cause this call to `INDEX` to return a value from the next row in column A.

You may need to experiment with different values of X (both positive and negative) for `COLUMN() + X` to correctly map the columns to the rows, depending on the position and shape of your table and the first place you put the formula before you drag it right.